# ADF: Can't get the for each paramter to work in the query for the sink

Tags: oracle, foreach, azure-data-factory

We have an Oracle database with a table and one of the tables holds dates. I want to itterate over this table by this date to copy dat from Oracle to Azure Datalake. But somehow I cannot get this to work.

The loopkup for the foreach works fine, but when I want to copy the data, using the one of the dates from the lookup, the copy activity task fails with the error: Message=ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-00936: missing expression

I suspect it has something to do with the dateformat that Oracle spits out en expects in the where clause. When I run the lookup-query in sql-developer, the dat format is like 29-DEC-14.

The query for the lookup looks like this:

```
select distinct activity_day
from Table 1
where activity_day < '01-JAN-15'
```

I restrict the data for testing so it only has to itterate everything before 01-01-2015 (which in this case is three rows)

In the foreach component items is stated as follows:

```
@activity('LookupDates').output.value
```

In the Copy activity the sink is specified as an Oracle query (connection to the oracle database works fine)

```
select column1, column2, coumn3,.......
from Table
where activity_day = @item().activity_day
```

The result should be that I get three files in my datalake with the data from three days. But as stated earlier, it fails in the copy activity on the source side. complet error below here:
"errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-00936: missing expression,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-00936: missing expression,Source=msora28.dll,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy Data1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was given on MSDN: in combination with another ttopic on stackoverflow:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4224338f-9511-4f80-9fbf-4bf4cbc1b596/cant-get-lookup-data-passed-to-oracle-database?forum=AzureDataFactory